Sitcom: small group of innovative coders vs huge, uncreative corporation
I'm trying to find the name of a sitcom in English about the digital economy. I cannot give a lot of details because I only read about this sitcom on a blog post a few days ago. Unfortunately, the blog post gave a few scant details about the sitcom plot, but it didn't mention its name: it characterized it as "a popular sitcom". Apparently, it's so popular that they didn't deem necessary to mention its name. The blog was American, thus I guess the sitcom is American too: it's surely in English. Since the post was recent (a couple of weeks ago, at most), it's likely that the sitcom is still airing, or at least is a recent one. 
According to the blog, the plot should involve a team of brilliant, misfit coders and developers fighting a tough battle against a mega-corporation with unlimited resources but no inspiration. It sounds like the kind of stuff I'd dig (I loved the IT Crowd and The Big Bang Theory) so I'd really appreciate any help.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question

@Paulie_D I tried, but the problem is that I actually don't have more details. Since I read about this sitcom on a recent blog post, I thought it was a recent and easily identifiable one....

The Silicon Valley is the most likely, but another candidate is The IT crowd. Less likely but another IT group battling the idiocracy of the rest of the corporation. Cult following among coders/netizens.

You're likely talking about HBO's Silicon Valley.

In the high-tech gold rush of modern Silicon Valley, the people most qualified to succeed are the least capable of handling success. A comedy partially inspired by Mike Judge's own experiences as a Silicon Valley engineer in the late 1980s.

It's about a group of coders and misfits battling large corporations (mainly Hooli). It wrapped up its 4th season not long ago. Here's the trailer:




This is excellent! It's definitely the kind of sitcom I'd like to binge watch now. Also, given that the blog post was about IT, technology, ML, etc. it's very likely they were referring to this show. Thank you!

@DeltaIV It's pretty good. It was touch and go for me at first because it's a bit repetitive and jargon-y, but it grew on me. Anyway, glad you found it, and welcome to M&TV! :)
